# I have RecyclerView which populates the feeds. In top of the recyclerview there is portion for feeds to be inserted

Tags: android

I have `RecyclerView` which populates the feeds. In top of the `RecyclerView` there is portion for feeds to be posted like status and photos from the gallery.

[image: Screen Shot of the app]

To post status I made `Adapter` which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`. In this adapter I can perform some `onClickListener`. But the problem I'm facing is with choosing image from gallery. How can I choose Image from gallery with the button click inside `Adapter`?

Below method can be used for this purpose but it works in Activity, but I need this method in Adapter because the `onClickListener` is inside the `ViewHolder` in `Adapter`.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help will be very appropriated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your `Activity` can hold a reference of your adapter and you create a method to call in your `Adapter`, or (and I think it's best) broadcast an event from your activity containing the `path` and listen to it with your adapter.

You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send your event (via an `Intent`), with the `path` as extra. And add a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to your `Adapter` to listen to it using [onAttachedToRecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onAttachedToRecyclerView(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)) to add your receiver, and [onDetachedFromRecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onDetachedFromRecyclerView(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)) to remove it.

Then you only have to bind your button like and image like that:

```
private Bitmap bitmap; // This variable will store your bitmap data

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    // Do that only if it's the post view

    holder.uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO start your media selection view here
        }
    });

    if( bitmap != null )
    {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } 
}
```

And when you get the callback from the `BroadcastReceiver`, just get the image like you would do and store it as a data:

```
@override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Uri filePath = getThePathFromTheIntent(intent); // TODO implement that one

    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), filePath);
}
```

Don't forget to clear the bitmap when done use it for memory management purpose.

Comment: RecyclerView is in the fragment and the button click listener is inside the ViewHolder of RecyclerView.Adapter. How can I perform the task in adapter to choose image and show it in imagView after choosing which is not visible at a time (will be visible after choosing image from gallary). How to do this inside the adapter which is Adaptername extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptername.ViewHolder>{...}

Comment: Added some logic to my answer to make it clearer how to do it. You may also want to call `notifyItemChanged` on your adapter to update the view when needed. Does that makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes you are probably solving my problem. I understand the onRecieve part of your answer. But would you please make the onClick part little bit more clearer, how can I choose image from gallery. Help me with the snippet.  I will surely tick your answer.

Comment: Well if you want to communicate with your activity/fragment to launch your image chooser, you probably want to send a broadcast, and add a receiver into your activity/fragment to handle the work.